# OpenJDK cannot see files on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I installed OpenJDK 14.0.2 2020-07-14 on my Unbuntu machine.

The following returns false, even though the file exists:

```
// returns false
new File("/usr/bin/firefox").exists();
```

I checked it simply using:

```
ls -lh /usr/bin/firefox
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Dec 14 03:54 /usr/bin/firefox -> ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

A file on my desktop works just fine:

```
// returns true
new File("/home/dev/Desktop/notes").exists();
```

I tried the same thing in Python:

```
# returns True
os.path.isfile("/usr/bin/firefox")
```

Is there something in the OpenJDK installation I need to change in order to allow it to see these files?

I installed OpenJDK 14 via `apt` so I can see it in the list:

```
openjdk-14-jdk-headless/groovy,now 14.0.2+12-1 amd64 [installed]
openjdk-14-jre-headless/groovy,now 14.0.2+12-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Thanks as always!

---

**Update**

Upon further investigation this is only happening in IntelliJ IDEA (I am using 2020.3). If I run my test from the command line this works just fine, ergo I am thinking this is an IDE issue. I will post any updates that I find.

Command I used to test this locally:

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.sometesting.TestFileExists
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to fix this.

The problem seems to be that I installed my IDEs via flatpak. When I removed IntelliJ IDEA from the flatpak installed and manually downloaded and installed it on my own everything worked fine. I went through and found some other flatpak projects where I could reproduce the issue.

If anyone else has issues I recommend looking at this:

https://davejansen.com/give-full-filesystem-access-to-flatpak-installed-applications/